# How to update Gtk.ListStore data efficiently in python

Tags: python-3.x, treeview, pygtk

I'm at the last stages of completing my program's transition from Tkinter to Gtk. The last step is updating the ListStore in an efficient manner. So far, what I'm trying is working...but for only about 15-120 seconds before it crashes (error code is 139; sometimes a coredump with no other message, sometimes a "Warning: corrupted double-linked list detected"). While it's running, `top` reports less than 100 MB of RAM in use.

The ListStore contains 51 rows with 25 columns, created as follows:

```
def init_ListStore():
    # initialize the main ListStore database
    for symbol in cbp_symbols.keys():
        name = cbp_symbols[symbol]['name']
        row = [symbol, name, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        liststore1.append(row)
    treeview1.set_model(liststore1)

    cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    columns = list(my_vars['liststore_main']['column_data'].keys())
    for i in range(liststore1.get_n_columns()):
        treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(columns[i])
        treeview1.append_column(treeviewcolumn)
        treeviewcolumn.pack_start(cell, True)
        treeviewcolumn.add_attribute(cell, "text", i)
```

After this is done, I do the following (3) steps:

Update my account information (token balances), get a new message from the websocket (stored as dictionary), update the new info, on a cell-to-cell basis, something like:

```
liststore1[row][col.index('Open')] = float(ticker_data["open_24h"])
liststore1[row][col.index('Last')] = float(ticker_data["price"])
liststore1[row][col.index('Low')] = float(ticker_data["low_24h"])
liststore1[row][col.index('High')] = float(ticker_data["high_24h"])
liststore1[row][col.index('Volume')] = float(ticker_data["volume_24h"])
```

I would like to be able to edit/replace the entire row in one shot; the above seems slow and burdensome. Once the initial creation/updates are done, everything is being done with the same function (there are about 20 total updates to be made with each message).

UPDATE #1: this time I got a more definitive error. The problem is in the `lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py` module, line 1680:

```
if GTK2 or GTK3:
    _Gtk_main_quit = Gtk.main_quit

    @override(Gtk.main_quit)
    def main_quit(*args):
        _Gtk_main_quit()

    _Gtk_main = Gtk.main

    @override(Gtk.main)
    def main(*args, **kwargs):
        with register_sigint_fallback(Gtk.main_quit):
            with wakeup_on_signal():
                return _Gtk_main(*args, **kwargs)   << this line
```

UPDATE #2: I *think* this is related to multithread locking, but I don't have a clue how that works (module is imported by the websocket client, not by me). I did try to apply a lock on the main function that parses the incoming socket message, but it didn't help. I *do* know that if I run the program without the Gtk window active, it never crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working. The trick was to use Gtk.TreeIter to reference the current row, then update the entire row in one shot:

```
titer = liststore1.get_iter(row)
my_columns = [
    df.columns.get_loc('Last') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Open') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Change') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Change %') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Low') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('High') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Value') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Val Open') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Port %') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Cost Basis') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('CB Change') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Value') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Val Open') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Profit') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Volume') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('30d Avg') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Vol Act %') + 1,
    df.columns.get_loc('Trade Val') + 1
]
my_data = [
    df.at[row, 'Last'],
    df.at[row, 'Open'],
    df.at[row, 'Change'],
    df.at[row, 'Change %'],
    df.at[row, 'Low'],
    df.at[row, 'High'],
    df.at[row, 'Value'],
    df.at[row, 'Val Open'],
    df.at[row, 'Port %'],
    df.at[row, 'Cost Basis'],
    df.at[row, 'CB Change'],
    df.at[row, 'Value'],
    df.at[row, 'Val Open'],
    df.at[row, 'Profit'],
    df.at[row, 'Volume'],
    df.at[row, '30d Avg'],
    df.at[row, 'Vol Act %'],
    df.at[row, 'Trade Val']
]
liststore1.set(titer, my_columns, my_data)
```

I know this code needs to be streamlined, but I tend to get something working first, then simplify/streamline afterwards.